# Parent category name included in subcategories URL pages?

Tags: symfony

My web app includes a group of categories and subcategories of products, that I have to show them at the navigation bar for example.

To relate categories and subcategories I have created a one to many relation to the Category entity itself, so I have this properties:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Categoria", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categoria", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $parent;
```

And I'm using the sluggable behavior like this:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

so the url are like this:

```
products/category_name
```

Now, for the pages related to the subcategories I would like to show an URL like this:

```
products/category_name/subcategory_name
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively simple:

1. pass multiple arguments to create the respective path in twig:

   {{ path('category_show', {'parentSlug': entity.getParent.slug, 'slug': entity.slug}) }}
2. set your route

   ```
   category_show:
       pattern:  /products/{parentSlug}/{slug}
   ```